# EF6: DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString changes after calling ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I am observing a weird behavior in EF6 `DbContext`.  My custom `DbContext` class reads its connection string from my App.config:

```
public partial class WorkobjectContext : DbContext
{
    public WorkobjectContext()
        : base("name=MainConnectionString")
    {
        // Set the initializer to null to disable intializtion otherwise EF tries to create the table if it does not exist (CreateDatabaseIfNotExists)
        Database.SetInitializer<WorkobjectContext>(null);
    }
}
```

As I am using the same connection string for my Ado.NET functions, I try to read the connection string out of `DbContext`:

```
var connectionstring = this.MyContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

But now I am observing that `this.MyContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` changes as I call `ExecuteCommand`:

```
...
Console.WriteLine(this.WorkobjectContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
// Output: DATA SOURCE=XXXX:1000/XXXX.XXXX;PASSWORD=MyPassword;USER ID=MyUserId

var ret = this.WorkobjectContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "BEGIN WPK_Inbox.Check_WOB_User(:pn_UserID, :pn_WOBID, :pn_Return, :pvErrorMsg, :pnErrorCode); end;",
    new object[]
    {
        userIdParameter,wobIdParameter,returnValueParameter,errorMsgParameter,errorCodeParameter
    }
    );
    
Console.WriteLine(this.WorkobjectContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
// Output: DATA SOURCE=XXXX:1000/XXXX.XXXX;PUSER ID=MyUserId
```

As you can see, after calling `ExecuteSqlCommand` the connection string changes and the password part disappears.
Why is this happening? Is this a bug?

Comment: Set `Persist Security Info=true` in the connection string?

Comment: Or just don't use `WorkobjectContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`. Instead, either work with the connection object as is or re-read the connection string from config, if you really need the password