# EF6: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I am getting frustrated about this, as I have tried out everything.
I have a backend project which uses EF6 (6.4.4) to connect to the database. There I have a `DbContext`:

```
public partial class WorkobjectContext : DbContext
{
    public WorkobjectContext()
        : base(DatabaseManager.ConnectionString)
    {
        // Set the initializer to null to disable intializtion otherwise EF tries to create the table if it does not exist (CreateDatabaseIfNotExists)
        Database.SetInitializer<WorkobjectContext>(null);
    }
    public virtual DbSet<DomainLayer.WorkobjectView> WorkobjectViews { get; set; }
}
```

Where `DatabaseManager.ConnectionString` is defined as following:

```
public static String ConnectionString => System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Now I have a UI project which uses this backend and it works perfect. I can use the backend and load data with EF6 from my oracle database.
The problem happens when I create a user control and reference `WorkobjectContext`:

```
var context = new WorkobjectContext();
```

Still here the UI-Application compiles successfully. But as I try to add this user control to somewhere else (another user control or a form) then the designer of Visual Studio 2015 does not work and shows the following error:

```
The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.
```

The callstack shows the following error message:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
at Workflow.Backend.InfrastructureLayer.Context.WorkobjectContext..ctor() in Workflow.Backend\InfrastructureLayer\Context\WorkobjectContext.cs:line 14
at Inbox.Modules.UcWorkobjectFilterPane..ctor() in Inbox\Modules\Workobjects\UcWorkobjectFilterPane.cs:line 26
```

This is despite the fact that the project is compiled and run successfully.
I tried different things to overcome this problem:

1. Assign the connectionstring directly to `DatabaseManager.ConnectionString`: `public static String ConnectionString => "DATA SOURCE=XXX-XXX-XXX.XXX:3333/XXX.TSTFRA;PASSWORD=XXX;USER ID=XXX";`
2. Change the constructor of `WorkobjectContext`: `public WorkobjectContext() : base(DatabaseManager.ConnectionString!= null ? DatabaseManager.ConnectionString: "DATA SOURCE=XXX-XXX-XXX.XXX:3333/XXX.TSTFRA;PASSWORD=XXX;USER ID=XXX")`

None of them works and the designer fails and shows the mentioned error message.
What is the reason for this problem? How can I overcome that?

**UPDATE:**
I found out, if I do the following:

```
public WorkobjectContext() : base("DATA SOURCE=XXX-XXX-XXX.XXX:3333/XXX.TSTFRA;PASSWORD=XXX;USER ID=XXX")
```

and clean and rebuild the solution and restart visual studio (important to restart visual studio), then the error disappears. After restarting, I can undo the change:

```
public WorkobjectContext() : base(DatabaseManager.ConnectionString)
```

and the error is not shown until I restart visual studio again. After restarting the visual studio with the undone changes, then the error reappears.
What is the reason for this problem?

**UPDATE:**
My last achievement:
If I change `DatabaseManager.ConnectionString` to the following, then the designer seems to work and does not show any error messages:

```
public static String ConnectionString => System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString) ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"]?.ConnectionString :
    "DATA SOURCE=XXX-XXX-XXX.XXX:3333/XXX.TSTFRA;PASSWORD=XXX;USER ID=XXX";
```

Comment: If you debug and look at the value it has when it assigns that connection string what does it say? Does it have the right value, or is it in fact empty?

Comment: @Jeff, it has the correct value and is non-empty. I am able to load data with it.

Comment: What about `base("name=MainConnectionString")`? Let EF read your configuration for you...

Comment: @grek40 I have used that version in the first place. But there seems to be a bug in EF6 if you use this connectionstring with DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. I have described the buggy behavior in another thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601632/ef6-dbcontext-database-connection-connectionstring-changes-after-calling-execut. Therefore, I have to use a global object to prevent EF6 from changing the connectionstring.

Comment: I commented about `Persist Security Info` in the other question. I highly recommend you abandon this approach and revisit your original problems with the `name=XYZ` approach.

Comment: You can simply read connection string from app.config and store it in a global variable to assign it back to your constructor. What I think is that the code is unable to pass connection string correctly to base constructor. In EF6 you can just specify name of connection string without giving the full connection string as base("name=YourConnectionStringName")

Comment: @Harkiratsingh, no this made no difference. At the beginning, I have used your mentioned approach and the problem happened, too.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe MainConnectionString that you read from your web config having some typo. Try checking if MainConnectionString in webconfig and MainConnectionString in your context is the same exact name. This stuff mainly caused by typos

Comment: @AvivDay, no there is no type. They are exactly the same.

Comment: It seems you are using a plain SqlClient connection string, then provider is missing. You can either use a entity connection string builder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8, or as mentioned, set it like that in configuration file: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/25601955/setting-provider-and-connection-string-in-entityframework-for-mysql